Node.js MSAL Authentication - Certificate Not Registered Error (invalid_client)
I'm using Node.js with the MSAL library to acquire a token for accessing my API. However, I'm running into an issue where I'm constantly getting an invalid_client error. Below is my code snippet:
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { ConfidentialClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-node'; 
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const clientId = '<MY_CLIENT_ID>';
const tenantId = '<MY_TENANT_ID>';
const thumbprint = '<MY_CERT_THUMBNAIL>';
const scopes = ['.default'];

// Paths to the certificate and key files
const certPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "Cert.crt");
const keyPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "Key.key");

// Read the certificate and private key files
const cert = fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'utf8');
const privateKeySource = fs.readFileSync(keyPath, 'utf8');

// Create the private key object
const privateKeyObject = crypto.createPrivateKey({
    key: privateKeySource,
    format: 'pem'
});

// Export the private key in the required format
const privateKey = privateKeyObject.export({
    format: 'pem',
    type: 'pkcs8'
});

// Remove certificate headers and footers, and encode to base64
const certBase64 = cert
  .replace(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/g, '')
  .replace(/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/g, '')
  .replace(/\n/g, '');

// Define the MSAL configuration
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
      clientId: clientId, 
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`, 
      clientCertificate: {
          thumbprint: thumbprint,
          privateKey: privateKey,
          x5c: [certBase64] 
      }
  },
  system: {
      loggerOptions: {
          loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
              console.log(message);
          },
          piiLoggingEnabled: false,
          logLevel: 'Verbose',
      }
  }
};

// Create the confidential client application instance
const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

// Define the client credential request
const clientCredentialRequest = {
  scopes: scopes,
  skipCache: false,
};

// Acquire token by client credential
cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Access token: ", response.accessToken);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error acquiring token: ", error);
  });

But I'm constantly getting the following error:
{
  errorCode: 'invalid_client',
  errorMessage: "700027 - [2024-05-31 06:36:17Z]: AADSTS700027: The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: '<MY_CERT_THUMBNAIL>', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '<MY_CLIENT_ID>'. Review the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the corresponding service endpoint and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to build a query request URL, such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<MY_CLIENT_ID>']. Trace ID: **** Correlation ID: **** Timestamp: 2024-05-31 06:36:17Z - Correlation ID: **** - Trace ID: ****",
  subError: '',
  errorNo: 700027,
  correlationId: '****'
}

Everything appears to be correctly configured in the Azure portal. The certificate is uploaded, and its thumbprint matches the one in the code. I've verified the client ID and tenant ID as well.
Could anyone point out what might be wrong with my code or configuration?

Additional Information:

Node.js version: Node 20.0.0
@azure/msal-node: 2.8.1
Azure AD Application is configured with the certificate and its thumbprint.
The certificate is correctly uploaded in the Azure AD Application under Certificates & secrets.


Initially, I generated private key and self-signed certificate using OpenSSL with below commands:
# Generate a private key
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out Key.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

# Generate a certificate signing request (CSR)
openssl req -new -key Key.key -out Cert.csr

# Self-sign the certificate (valid for 365 days)
openssl x509 -req -in Cert.csr -signkey Key.key -out Cert.crt -days 365

Response:

Now, I registered one Azure AD application and uploaded Cert.crt file in Certificates & secrets tab like this:

When I ran below code, I got the access token successfully in response like this:
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { ConfidentialClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-node'; 
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

// Resolve __filename and __dirname for ES6 modules
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

// Replace these values with your actual Azure AD app details
const clientId = 'appId';
const tenantId = 'tenantId';
const thumbprint = 'cert_thumbprint'; 
const scopes = ['.default'];

// Paths to the certificate and key files
const certPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "Cert.crt");
const keyPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "Key.key");

// Read the certificate and private key files
const cert = fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'utf8');
const privateKeySource = fs.readFileSync(keyPath, 'utf8');

// Create the private key object
const privateKeyObject = crypto.createPrivateKey({
    key: privateKeySource,
    format: 'pem'
});

// Export the private key in the required format
const privateKey = privateKeyObject.export({
    format: 'pem',
    type: 'pkcs8'
});

// Remove certificate headers and footers, and encode to base64
const certBase64 = cert
  .replace(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/g, '')
  .replace(/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/g, '')
  .replace(/\n/g, '');

// Define the MSAL configuration
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
      clientId: clientId, 
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`, 
      clientCertificate: {
          thumbprint: thumbprint,
          privateKey: privateKey,
          x5c: [certBase64] 
      }
  },
  system: {
      loggerOptions: {
          loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
              console.log(message);
          },
          piiLoggingEnabled: false,
          logLevel: 'Verbose',
      }
  }
};

// Create the confidential client application instance
const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

const clientCredentialRequest = {
  scopes: scopes,
  skipCache: false,
};

// Acquire token by client credential
cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Access token: ", response.accessToken);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error acquiring token: ", error);
  });

Response:

The error usually occurs if the certificate is not uploaded to right Azure AD app registration:

In your case, check whether there are duplicate applications/certificates with same application name and confirm whether you uploaded correct certificate to right app registration or not.
If still the error persists, try creating new app registration and follow above mentioned steps again to acquire token.

Its was duplicate certificate in another app that was causing an issue.
